# How to auto configure war file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, war

I have a problem with my war.xml file in that it isn't picking up my class files correctly for spring.

The line that is wrong is:

```
<dir sourceOnDisk="C:\myApp\src\main\java" targetInArchive="/WEB-INF/classes"/>
```

I need:

```
<dir sourceOnDisk="C:\myApp\bin" targetInArchive="/WEB-INF/classes"/>
```

Now, I can change the file manually (from src\main\java to bin), and it works correctly for a while, but every now and again something decides my war.xml file needs to be rebuilt, and things then break again.

I added my application by dragging my project from eclipse's Project Explorer tab to my liberty profile server instance within eclipse's Servers tab.

Where is the menu option within eclipse to change this?

Comment: do you want the whole file? The relevant line is included in the question. When I change it to bin everything works until eclipse or something changes it back.

Comment: maybe you mean 'web.xml'?

Comment: The TSP.war.xml file lives here: C:\eclipse\runtime\usr\servers\jhServer\apps. So it's in the directory that liberty profile application server needs it to be in.

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: we build it with gradle once at the start. This uses maven to download jars. Subsequent code changes take place in eclipse

Comment: Someone (eclipse?) thinks that you are using maven and changes path to `src\main\java`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the correct place to change things is in the Deployment Assembly option when you right click on your project...

Answer (score 2):

To automatically map your bin folder to the WEB-INF/classes folder, select your project on the Project Explorer, right click it and select **Java Build Path**. In this property page on the **Source** tab, you can add, edit or remove the source folder, and also modify the default output folder. In this case you may only need to modify the output folder, to something similar to **(project-name)/bin**

Regarding the *war.xml file located at **(server-dir)/apps**, this will be refreshed each time you modify your project in eclipse, if when doing it, you have your server started and with automatic publish enabled. Usually you don't modify this file yourself, but you can read more about it here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_loose_applications.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-14-1-10